# modal not opening after generated

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I am in the process of creating a support ticket system, however I have ran into a problem with getting generated modals to open. Below you will find the code that generates the list of tickets (As well as the button to open the modal) along with the modal generation itself.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter">
<tbody>
    <?php
        $Status = $_GET['filter'];
        $DataArray = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE Status='$Status'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($DataArray)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-w600 text-center" style="width: 80px;">#TCK<?php echo $row['ticketID']; ?></td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md text-center" style="width: 100px;">
            <?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Open') { echo "<span class=\"label label-success\">Open</span>";}elseif($row['Stauts'] == 'Pending'){echo"<span class=\"label label-warning\">In Progress</span>";}else{echo "<span class=\"label label-danger\">Resolved</span>";} ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="font-w600" data-toggle="modal" data-target=<?php echo $row['ticketID']; ?> href="#"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></a>
            <div class="text-muted">
                <em><?php echo humanTiming($row['Created']); ?> ago</em> by <a href="/base_pages_profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['UserID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Username']; ?></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md text-muted" style="width: 120px;">
            <em><?php echo $row['Catagory']; ?></em>
        </td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md text-center" style="width: 60px;">
            <span class="badge badge-primary"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> <?php echo CountTicketComments($con,$row['ticketID']); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

The above snippet is where I generate the table of tickets, 'data-target' should be the name of the modal as im aware, in this case i simply set the data-target to the tickets ID.

```
<?php
$Status = $_GET['filter'];
$DataArray = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE Status='$Status'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($DataArray)) {
?>
 <div class="modal fade" id=<?php echo $row['ticketID']; ?> tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-popout">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

Lastly the above snipped is where I generate each modal (I removed the content to reduce clutter) as you can see I set the modal's 'id' to the ticketID just as I did with the data-target...

So I am unsure as to why this is not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data-target` attribute should be set to `#elementID` you're missing the `#` character at the start.

Try:

```
 <a ... data-target="#<?php echo $row['ticketID']; ?>" ... > ... </a>
```